# Modal fixed, content scrollable in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new in react native.

My question is pretty simple: I have modal with avatar, some information about current person and some details, I need modal height to be fixed, and content from ScrollView  must be scrollable, how to fix it? Any suggestion how to solve? Here is my code:

```
        <Modal transparent={true} animationType={'slide'} visible={visible}>
        <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} />
        <View style={[styles.mainContainer, { width: width - 60 }]}>
            <View
                style={[
                    styles.modalContent,
                    { width: width - 50, maxHeight: height - insets.bottom - insets.top - 20 }
                ]}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressClose}>
                    <Close style={styles.closeButton} width={30} height={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
                    <Avatar.Image
                        style={styles.avatarCollegue}
                        size={90}
                        source={require('../../../assets/images/collegue1.png')}
                    ></Avatar.Image>
                    <View style={styles.infoCollegue}>
                        <Text style={styles.collegueName}>Sandra Vinke</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.collegueJob}>Commerciel Directeur</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.collegueDetail, { height: height - 50 }]}>

                    <ScrollView style={styles.aboutCollegue}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.currentUserDetail}>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                                reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                                laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                                amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum
                                blanditiis maxime autem, e laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                                reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                                reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                                laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                                amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum
                                blanditiis maxime autem, e laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates, Lorem
                                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                                reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                                laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                                amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum
                                blanditiis maxime autem, e laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates, Lorem
                                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                                reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                                laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                                amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum
                                blanditiis maxime autem, e laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCollegue}>
                        <View style={styles.emailButtonCollegue}>
                            <Text style={styles.contactCurrentCollegue}>{I18n.t('MYCOLLEGUES.EMAIL_BUTTON')}</Text>
                            <Email width={15} height={15} style={styles.iconButton} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I fix it

```
<ScrollView style={{height: 250}}>
                        <Text style={styles.currentUserDetail}>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates,
                            reprehenderit laborum architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis
                            laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum blanditiis maxime
                            autem, e laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt, Lorem ipsum dolor
                            sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sequi voluptates, reprehenderit laborum
                            architecto ex fugiat fugit incidunt aspernatur. Ab corporis laborum dolores at eum
                            asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt in? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                            adipisicing elit. Aperiam cum minus soluta dignissimos eum blanditiis maxime autem, e
                            laborum dolores at eum asperiores obcaecati ipsa deserunt
                        </Text>
                    </ScrollView>
```